# After overriding create function, how to the get the id of the newly created object in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet and I want to perform some more operations on the newly created object. But I am unable to get the newly created object id here.
How to get the newly created object id after the super()?

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone = request.data.get('student_phone_number')
        batch_id = request.data.get('batch_id')
        class_number = request.data.get('class_number')
        if not any([phone, batch_id, class_number]):
            return Response({"message": "Missing Params"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if self.queryset.filter(student_phone_number=phone, batch_id=batch_id, class_number=class_number,
                                is_cancelled=False).exists():
            return Response({"message": "Compensation class already booked"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Have tried checking the return value of super create ? It would be returning tuple first element being the object created.

Comment: that returns a HTTP response object with status code 201 (created).

Comment: have a look at source code of `create` method, you can simply miss the `super` call and get your newly created instance using serializer, i.e. `instance = serializer.save()` and then perform your logic. By the way, I would suggest you validating the missing fields in the same serializer.

Comment: @Ersain, thank you. Your answer was really helpful, after this, it was a 5sec change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should overwrite the perform_create not create Method on ModelViewSet

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    phone_value = self.request.data['phone']
    batch_id_value = self.request.data['batch_id']
    class_number_value = self.request.data['class_number']

    // do your condition here

    instance = serializer.save(phone=phone_value, batch_id=batch_id_value, class_number=class_number_value)
    
    instance_id = instance.id

    // do whatever you want with instance_id 

    return Response({"message": "Data Has been saved", Id:instance_id }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Calling serializer.save() should return the instance that has just been create.